# R Sequence of numbers to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with many rows, I'd like to add a column that counts along every xth row and label it accordingly, for example:

```
ROW    LABEL
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      2
6      2
7      2
8      2
9      3
9      3
```

And so on, where ROW is the row of my Dataframe .I'd like to be able to alter the LABEL count, in the example I have shown the label count is set to 4 (every 4th row increment the label).
Any help appreciated.

P.

Comment: You have row 9 twice...

Answer (score 2):

Two words: [integer division](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html).

Using `rep()`:

```
N <- 4L; df$LABEL <- rep(seq_len(nrow(df)%/%N+1L),each=N,len=nrow(df));
df;
##   ROW LABEL
## 1   1     1
## 2   2     1
## 3   3     1
## 4   4     1
## 5   5     2
## 6   6     2
## 7   7     2
## 8   8     2
## 9   9     3
```

Using `seq()`:

```
N <- 4L; df$LABEL <- seq(0L,len=nrow(df))%/%N+1L;
df;
##   ROW LABEL
## 1   1     1
## 2   2     1
## 3   3     1
## 4   4     1
## 5   5     2
## 6   6     2
## 7   7     2
## 8   8     2
## 9   9     3
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ROW=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rep` together with the each argument:

```
rep(1:4, each=4)
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Then to assign it:

```
df$label <- rep(1:4, each=4)
```

To get this to be more dynamic, you can feed the x argument a measure of the total rows:

```
df$label <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(df) / 4), each=4)
```

This assumes that the total number of rows are divisible by 4. If they are not, you can also include the length.out argument (as suggested by @Frank) to set the correct the length difference:

```
df$label <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(df) / 4), each=4, length.out=nrow(df))
```

It is also possible to feed rep a vector of different lengths to repeat each element in x if you want to vary the lengths of each label. For example:

```
rep(1:4, c(1, 2, 3, 4))
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

note that the length vector must have the same length as the x vector.

Comment: I need it to do it along varying number of rows of a given Dataframe....here i get an error because my dataframe is 20000+ rows long and the code generates 20 rows....I'm sure its a small tweak.

Comment: @PaulB `rep(seq(nrow(DF))/4, each=4)` ?

Comment: sorry this throws an error too, as it generates 4 times as many rows as my datafrane has. Thanks for this though, I think I can figure it out

Comment: Regarding the divisible-by-four issue, `rep`'s `length.out` option might help.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. great tip. I had never tried to combine those before.

Comment: Maybe something like this? It works in my 51-row test dataframe.
`rep(1:nrow(x), each=4, length.out = nrow(x))`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBrēza. I added the `ceiling` function to take care of the rounding issue you might be alluding to: `identical(rep(1:51, each=4, length.out = 51), rep(1:ceiling(51 / 4), each=4, length.out = 51))` returns TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code. You can change the number of labels and repetitions in the first two lines.

```
labelQuantity <- 4
repeatLabel <- 4
label <- rep(1:labelQuantity,1,each=repeatLabel)
row <- seq(1,length(label),1)
myDataFrame <- as.data.frame(cbind(row,label))
```

Cheers!